# WMI access denied error when query remote computer from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, security, powershell, wmi

I have an ASP.NET application that executes a WMI call to a remote system. The application Web.config contains <identity impersonate="true"> and <authentication mode="Windows"> options which, as I understand, should force the application code to be executed on behalf of the application user.

The problem is that I get "Access is denied" error, despite the fact I can successfully execute the my WMI request from PowerShell console on the same host under the same user to the remote server in question.

```
// this doesn't work
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope();
scope.Path.NamespacePath = "root\\virtualization";
scope.Path.Server = "vs01";
scope.Connect(); // <-- here comes exception

# this works just fine
Get-WmiObject -Namespace 'root\virtualization' -Class Msvm_ComputerSystem -ComputerName vs01
```

Dumping HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name, System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name, System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name properties suggest that impersonation works as expected.

Ideas? Could the issue be some kind of .NET or IIS security?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have a domain administrator enable Delegation for your web server machine.  This is a security feature of Kerberos.  By default an intermediate server (in this case your web server) is not allowed to pass the impersonation context of a client to the remote server unless it has been given Delegation permission.  If you don't do this the remote target server will see the request coming in as Anonymous User... which if its properly secured will be denied access.

Note its a common policy to only allow an intermediate server to delegate to specific target servers (called constrained delegation), so if your web app needs to be able to call WMI on any server in your network you may have problem.  Talk to your domain admin.

Comment: Thank you, delegation permissions partially helped. Now I can make a call, but I have to enter my credentials when accessing the page containing WMI code.

Comment: UPDATE: IE works just fine. Firefox and Chrome seem to work differently. I guess they do not provide full Kerberos info necessary for delegation.

Comment: IE implements the SPNEGO authentication protocol (Kerberos/NTLM), which gives you single sign on.  I don't think Firefox/Chrome implements this out of the box so what you may be seeing is NTLM pass-thru authentication.  This is one reason for standardizing around IE for internal apps in a Windows domain.

Comment: How do you enable Delegation for your web server machine?  IIS 7?