# Running wmi queries as a non-admin user on a remote machine using C#

Tags: c#, windows, active-directory, wmi

I am trying to use **WMI** to query system information on some clients on our network. We have successfully used administrator users to accomplish this in C# but now we want to switch to users **without admin permissions** (just enough permissions to run wmi queries accross the network) due to security reasons.

I can successfully run wmi queries using powershell as a user without elevated admin permissions on a remote host using `Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName pcname`

I have an application trying to accomplish the same thing using C#:

The following snippet should use the user which runs the application without further authentication required:

```cs
CimSession session = CimSession.Create(hostname);

// A method called GetWMI(string query, string namespace) will then execute the wmi query on the remote machine
session.QueryInstances(namespace, "WQL", query)
```

I also tried using in-code authentication with dcomsettings (of course using the same user credentials which can perform the same request using powershell as seen above):

```cs
DComSessionOptions dComOptions = new DComSessionOptions();
dComOptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationType.Impersonate;
var password = new SecureString();
settings.WMIPassword.ToList().ForEach(x => password.AppendChar(x));
dComOptions.AddDestinationCredentials(new CimCredential(PasswordAuthenticationMechanism.Default, settings.WMIDomain, settings.WMIUsername, password));

CimSession session = CimSession.Create(hostname, dComOptions);

// A method called GetWMI(string query, string namespace) will then execute the wmi query on the remote machine
session.QueryInstances(namespace, "WQL", query)
```

Both of these ways end up throwing a `CimException: Access Denied` error.

Is there maybe another way to do this in C#? My research could not come up with anything that would work - maybe there is some way I don't know about yet.

We have sunk countless hours into research and debugging but nothing seems to work.

For future reference I have found some older posts regarding some similar issues (most information on the internet about wmi is over a decade old):

- [WMI - Using a non admin account to query server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552268/wmi-using-a-non-admin-account-to-query-server)
- The following is actually my own post regarding the same issue - it was resolved as we tried using administrator permissions on the remote machine which would work but we now need it to work with as little permissions as possible eg. no administrator
  [Access Denied trying to gather WMI information using C# ASP.NET but works in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77911911/access-denied-trying-to-gather-wmi-information-using-c-sharp-asp-net-but-works-i)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/28520/which-permissions-rights-does-a-user-need-to-have-wmi-access-on-remote-machines/1105113#1105113
- [WMI access denied error when query remote computer from ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627394/wmi-access-denied-error-when-query-remote-computer-from-asp-net?rq=1)
- ["get-wmiobject win32_process -computername" gets error "Access denied , code 0x80070005"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952833/get-wmiobject-win32-process-computername-gets-error-access-denied-code-0x8/14953535#14953535)
- [Delphi Wmi Query on a Remote Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990890/delphi-wmi-query-on-a-remote-machine)

I have tried all the suggestions from these posts - some of them seemed promising but turned out to not be the solution of my problem.

Here is a summary of what we tried:

- We granted all permissions in "wmimgmt.msc" to the root namespace and applied them to "This namespace and subnamespaces"
- We added the user to the Local "Distributed COM Users" group
- We added the user to the "Performance Monitor Users"  and the "Remote Management Users" groups
- We checked for any firewall issues and can assure that that should not be the problem
- We also granted remote launch and activation permissions

Here is our configuration in "wmimgmt.mcs" which should apply to the root namespace and all namespaces below (it's in German but shows that all permissions should apply to all namespaces):
[image: wmimgmt.msc Configuration on the root namespace]

Furthermore I found an old post in the microsoft docs stating that this is actually impossible (which is hard to believe as I already got it to work using powershell): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc771551(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

> To perform this task on the local computer, you must be logged on as a member of the local Administrators group.

> To perform this task on a remote computer, the account with which you are logged on must be a member of the Administrators group of that computer.

If there is anything more I can provide to clear things up please let me know.

Any leads would be highly appreciated - if any of my points in this post help other people in the future it was at least worth the research.

Comment: The powershell case is not comparable as the query is different. Your pirmary issue is probably that the user doesn't have the right permissions for the namespace or query. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/securing-a-remote-wmi-connection "We granted all permissions in "wmimgmt.msc" to the root namespace" you'd need to show that because it sounds like that hasn't been done.

Comment: @Charlieface thanks for your comment! I have added a screenshot of our "wmimgmt.mcs" configuration in my post. Could you elaborate on what you mean that the Powershell case is different?

Comment: Likely, your problem is the user that is executing the asp.net application pool; this user should be the same as the website user, and the account must be allowed to impersonate. one thing I should warn you is that an asp-net application should not have there rightIt seems that the issue you are experiencing is related to the user executing the ASP.NET application pool. This user needs to be the same as the website user, and must have the permission to impersonate. It's important to note that an ASP.NET application should not have elevated rights.s

Comment: If I were you, I would create a local service that you communicate with using named pipes. The local service can then run under privileged rights and communicate with other systems that use the same service to synchronize.

Have a look at https://github.com/HavenDV; he has nice packages that do this"